# Firebase Cloud Functions Cannot find module error in logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I am trying to [Serve Dynamic Content with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) and [NextJS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/).

Everything is working as expected locally when I run `firebase serve`.

But when I run `firebase deploy` and try and run my function I get the below error in the firebase functions logs.

[image]

```
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/get-prototype-of'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/next/dist/pages/_document.js:7:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I am not directly using babel (I am using typescript) so one of my modules must be using it as a dependency.

I am guessing I have installed something globally on my local machine and it is not present in my cloud functions but how can I debug what this would be? I have tried adding `babel-runtime` to my package.json

`node -v v6.11.5`

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "build-js": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc && cp package.json ../../build/functions/package.json"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.39",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "googleapis": "^23.0.0",
    "next": "^4.2.1",
    "range-inclusive": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.39",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Typically you don't add typescript as a regular dependency.  It should probably be a dev dependency that you use only at build time to generate the JS to deploy.  Oh, and you are using @babel/runtime directly.  Is that what you intended?  Do you really need to use typescript and babel at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DougStevenson I was using it in devDependencies initially but just trialled it in dependencies incase google cloud only read dependencies for some reason.  With the @babel/runtime I don't need it for what I am doing I tried including it because I was getting the error. what would you recommend to do re babel. I have updated my package.json with what I have tried next and updated the question above?

Comment: I would just use the TypeScript configuration provided by the Firebase CLI and nothing else.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, could you resolve this?

Comment: @MartinReiche I got it working. I structure my app with src/app and src/functions. Any npm dependency I needed in app (my react app) I also added to the src/functions/package.json and this fixed the problem. Does that make sense. Feel free to add a gist or something and I can see if I can suggest anything once looking at your code?

Comment: @ak85 Thanks for your answer, I could resolve the issue the exact same way :)

Comment: good to hear @MartinReiche, all the best!

Comment: I too face the same issue. My dependencies do not include typescript or the babel.

    "@firebase/firestore": "^1.17.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.8.5",
    "@types/sharp": "^0.28.3",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.5.1",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "firebase": "7.21.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "geo-tz": "^6.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "luxon": "^1.28.0",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.14.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "4.2.5",
    "sharp": "^0.28.3",
    "twilio": "^3.52.0"

Answer (score 1):

Move `babel-runtime` from your `devDependencies` into your `dependencies`.

When you deploy, Google Cloud Functions only installs `dependencies`, it ignores `devDependencies`.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs